# Delphi : Deciding which component to create at runtime

Tags: delphi, oop

Problem:

A form is supposed to have a visual component.

There a 2 versions of the same component having same grandparent class. Each allows different kind of functionality.

Based on configuration parameters, the correct component should be loaded when the form loads.
By default, one of the component is present on the form at design time. At runtime, the application needs to decide whether to keep this component or discard it and load the other component with same event handlers and properties as the previous one PLUS some of its own which allow additional functionality. They are not from same inheritance branch.

In OOP terms:

TGrandParent -> TParent -> TDesiredComponent1 (**Present at design time. Loaded by default**.)
TGrandParent -> TDesiredComponent2 (**needs to load based on config**)

If I try to create both components at runtime, it works and correct component is loaded. The problem is, there are lots of event handlers attached to it and there are large number of such components.

It will be very good if this can be done concisely in one place. Any Idea how to achieve this?

Comment: This doesn't really sound like the right way to solve a problem. If I were you I'd look for a better design.

Comment: First of all if you are detemining which component is needed at runtime why are you even creating one at design time? Isn't that just a waste of CPU cycles (creating component just so that it will be destroyed a few ms later). Second of all how will you be accessing either of these components when they have different properties/methods? Yes I have seen that they share common properties/methods but how will you determine if it is posible to call some method of the "extended" component, when other component doesen't have this method?

Comment: The correct approach would be adding aditional abstract layer (a class or interface) which exposes all psoible properties and methods and then at runtime determines when some property can be accessed, or when certain method can be executed and returns some usefull result or warning if that isn't posible. Now this abstract layer should only forward the data returned from properties or methods of your two components or return some predefined result if your components don't have that method or property.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Both are custom components. 
The application is pretty large with number of forms and places where the Component1 is used as design time component. Component2 is supposed to add functionality at all those places based on config. So architecturally, not a lot of options to change usage of components.

Comment: Well, if you feel you are out of options, then so be it.

Comment: I don't think this sounds like a good design either. Why not create one component with two different modes? Such as the Tee Chart... One single control that can be switched to work in many different ways. Cleaner in the IDE too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've ended up doing - Create 2 versions of component1. One, which keeps old behavior, and one which is inherited from component2. I needed to keep the old version because changing the component globally was still giving problems at some places after new inheritance. Any better solution will be helpful, but this seems to be working pretty well, not checked for memory/performance issue though.
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score -1):

Once I used [TReader.OnCreateComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Classes.TReader.OnCreateComponent) event to do such trick. But generally I'd prefer more clear and wise design.

To be honest, once I'd used a more interesting trick: at runtime I located an Component1 VMT and changed it, so when Component1.NewInstance/Create had been called, Component2.NewInstance/Create had been really executed. It will definitely solve your problem :)